# How to get SWI-Prolog to always print strings with quotes, in interactive mode

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

When using SWI-prolog, it will print output that doesn't need to be quoted (output that doesn't contain special characters), without quotes.
As an example:

```
?- p('this_is_a_string').
true.

?- p(X).
X = this_is_a_string.
```

I would like Prolog to always output with quotes. It is okay if my output ends up quoting stuff like functor names, which were not originally quoted when input. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want this? It easily introduces new kinds of errors. See comment in answer you accepted.

Comment: I'm parsing the output of prolog, so I want consistent use of quotes.

Comment: Funny that you mentioned backslashes in an atom, I just encountered that issue, but it was fairly easy to fix, so not an issue.

Comment: What about `'\n'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the default behaviour of SWI-Prolog's top-level output, you want to look towards [setting a flag](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=flags#flag:user_flags). If you query the appropriate flag, you should find this is your default output:

```
?- current_prolog_flag(print_write_options, Options).
Options = [portray('true'), quoted('true'), numbervars('true')].
```

In this particular case, the needed flag is already set: we have `portray('true')` in our `Options`.

[`portray/1`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=portray/1) is a dynamic predicate that you can assert. It's called with a ground term when it is being printed, if it succeeds then it's assumed the the term has been printed.

So in your case you can assert the following:

```
portray(Term) :- atom(Term), format("'~s'", Term).
```

Now you'll get the desired behaviour:

```
?- p(this_is_an_atom).
true.

?- p(X).
X = 'this_is_an_atom'.
```

You could add this to your `.swiplrc` file if it's something you want all the time. Note, this will have no effect on `write/1` and similar predicates, you'll need to use this instead:

```
?- write_term(foo, [portray(true)]).
'foo'.
```

To add the additional requirement of escaping characters in the the atom, you'll either need to implement your own DCG to the ISO standard for escaping characters, or abuse the built-in one. To do this you can write out to an atom and see if you need to add your single-quotes, or if they would already be there. The case of `X = (\).` is most easily handled in its own clause, you can then choose if you wish to print `'\\'` or `(\)`.

```
portray(\) :-
    format("'\\\\'"), !.
portray(Term) :-
    atom(Term), \+ Term = (\),
    ( with_output_to(chars(['\''|_]),
        write_term(Term, [quoted(true), character_escapes(true), portrayed(false)]))
    -> format("~q", Term)
    ; format("'~s'", Term)
    ).
```

Comment: Incorrect, when quote or backslash is part of the atom

Comment: Not fixed: `Term = '\n'` produces `''\n''`

Comment: Or `Term = (\)` produces `'\'` which is invalid syntax, too

Comment: Well, you'd only get one output as portray/1 is only called once, but it is a simple matter to add a guard.

Comment: ... `\=` produces invalid syntax.

Comment: So does `atom('\=')` and `Var = '\='`, therefore I don't think '\=' is valid syntax for an atom... I also don't think that quoting operators is part of the requirements for parsing output?

Comment: `Var = (foo \= bar)` will output `('foo'\='bar')`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with operators. I just gave you a minimal example. But take `\===` which produces invalid syntax, too.

Comment: But `portray(\=)` works, `X = (\=)` works, and `X = (\====)` also works. I think the syntax error you're getting is because `'\='` is invalid syntax for an atom in SWI-Prolog. Do you find you get that as a syntax error when not using with my code? As an operator, it needs to be in parenthesis, as per your `(\)` example.

Comment: `portray(\===)` produces `'\==='` which is invalid syntax

Comment: Now I understand what you meant. It succeeded because `atom(\=)` succeeds. A simple guard forces it to fail, again this doesn't change the output as `portray/1` hook isn't called for operators as the `Var = (foo \= bar)` example demonstrated, but it is safer. Interestingly, as certain key words are operators in SWI-Prolog, you might find the behaviour of `X = 'public'.` unexpected.

Comment: Again, `'\='` is invalid syntax, idem `'\==='`

Comment: To avoid the unexpected behaviour of `X = 'public'`, would it not be better to remove the `current_op/3` guard and allow the procedural meaning of the Prolog take care of the operators such that if one of these key words is used as an atom then it would be printed quoted rather than in brackets?

Comment: As it stands with the `current_op/3` guard: `portray(\=)` will fail, as will `portray(\===)` and `portray(public)`. As a result: `?- X = (foo \= public).` will produce `X = ('foo'\=(public))`, whereas if we remove the `current_op/3` guard then it will produce `X = ('foo'\='public')`.

Comment: Again, I was not even into operators at all, just pure token syntax for one token.

Comment: Indeed, but it cannot be avoided as `portray/1` is a hook that is called for subterms and not for operators. I'm removing the guard to avoid unexpected behaviour. Therefore if an operator is in the position of an atom, it is quoted (`write_term(public, [portray(true)])` produces `'public'`), whereas an operator in the position of an operator is not quoted (`write_term(foo\=foo, [portray(true)])` produces `'foo'\='foo')`. Should someone using this answer wish to change this behaviour, they can reinstate the guard and add `portray/1` clauses to handle any atoms that are also operators

Comment: OP's idea was to simplify a parser to read Prolog text. All we can say is that this is not **that** simple. I assume OP does not want to handle priorities, but then this is my assumption. At least I now understand why you look so much into operators: SWI has changed some of its syntax rules in this area, mixing up operators and token syntax. (With ISO conforming syntax there are less troubles, and I was only looking at that part)